# Adjacency matrix of subdivision graph.

Tags: graph-theory, algorithms

Is there a way to get from an adjacency matrix of a simple graph to an arbitrary subdivision of the graph? I believe I found a way to get from $G$ to $G^{1/2}$ using the incidence matrix, but in particular I want a way to get from $G$ to $G^{1/3}$ without needing to manually type out 1600+ entries.

Comment: In the context of a graph, what do you mean by $G^{1/2}$ and $G^{1/3}$?

Comment: @MishaLavrov, sorry I've been using that notation so long I thought it was standard. $G^{1/2}$ is the first subdivision graph (one vertex has been put on every edge), while $G^{1/3}$ is the second (two vertices have been put on every edge).

Answer (score 1):

I assume that the graphs $G$ and $G^{1/3}$ are undirected. Let $A=\|a_{ij}\|$ be an adjacency $n\times n$-matrix of the graph $G$. Let $E=\{(i,j): i<j$ and $a_{ij}=1\}$. To obtain an adjacency matrix for the graph $G^{1/3}$ we add to the matrix $A$   $2|E|$  rows and $2|E|$ columns. Each of these rows and columns is indexed by a $(i,j,t)$, where $(i,j)\in E$ and $t\in \{1,2\}$. 
The only non-zero elements of the extended matrix $A$ are $a_{i, (i,j,1)}$, $a_{(i,j,1),i}$, $a_{j, (i,j,2)}$, $a_{(i,j,2),j}$, $a_{(i,j,1), (i,j,2)}$, and $a_{(i,j,2), (i,j,1)}$, where $i$ ranges over $1,\dots, n$ and $(i,j)$ ranges over $E$.